# Updating main table from different temp tables using stored procedure - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am having the following architecture where there are multiple python process writing data into temp tables in batches.

For simplicity, lets consider there are two python process (p1 and p2) and it pushes the data into 2 temp tables each as shown in the diagram.

I need to create a stored procedure which will fetch the data from temp tables (t1, t2, t3 and t4) and update the main table.

[image]

```
Questions:

if i create two stored procedures, (ie. one of each process) , will there be a lock while writing to database. How do we handle that.

For example, both P1 and P2 trigger at the same time and uploads data in temp tables. Now, if we two stored procedures S1 and S2 getting triggered. S1 writes the data into main table. However, S2 will get a WRITE_LOCK (my assumption).


If we have only one stored procedure overall, still the data will be updated sequentially and the python job P2 will have to wait until P1 is getting copied. 

The data we are handling is in GBs and has millions of records. 

Can you please suggest a suitable solution for this design ?
```

Comment: why do you want to use a stored procedure?  why to you want to even use temp tables instead of just inserting into your main table?  are these actual TEMPORARY tables or are you just meaning temp table to mean a transient location for the data?   are these two processes running at the same time?  do they finish at the same time?  what determines when you start copying from the temp tables?  are you trying to get them to copy in parallel or are you trying to get them to only copy sequentially?  are these innodb tables or myisam tables?

Comment: the two python process are running in parallel, each processing multiple jobs. First we want to stage the data created from the python process and then update the data to the main table . I would like to know, will there be a deadlock situation if it happends in parallel.

Comment: Do you suggest that we dont need to stage the data. What if we have 10 python process running and everything trying to insert data into main table at once.